# Modifying each object of a List in for each loop in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm fetching items from database. I have a few Edit Texts and I need to get text from these editable texts and pass that text, update too objects of a List I get from database. I'm getting values from Edit Texts. This is how it looks in code:

```
String getNasteMonday = etNasteMonday != null ? etNasteMonday.getText().toString() : null;
String getInsulinMondayBeforeBreak = etInsulinMondayBeforeBreak != null ? etInsulinMondayBeforeBreak.getText().toString() : null;    
List<Day> days = mDatabase.getAllDaysByWeek(week.getTitle());
double nasteValue = convertStringToDouble(getNasteMonday);
double insulinBeforeBreakValue = convertStringToDouble(getInsulinMondayBeforeBreak);

for (Day day : days) {
    day.setNaste(nasteValue);
    day.setInsulinBeforeBreak(insulinBeforeBreakValue);
    mDatabase.updateDay(day);
}
```

In this case I have three tables in database, one for storing days, and one for storing weeks and one for storing days by weeks. I'm fetching data in this case by week name and every Week object has 7 days and I need to store different values for each day in that Week. Now, what I'm getting is that in this foreach loop  I'm storing the same value for all 7 days and I don't want that. I want to do something like this for example:

```
for (Day day1 : days) {
    day1.setNaste(nasteValue);
}
for (Day day2 : days) {
    day2.setNaste(nasteValue2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

How to show text in EditText when i have fetched data from database:

I should set text from an array of Strings.

```
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.et_naste_monday, R.id.et_insulin_monday_before_breakf, R.id.et_posle_dorucka_monday, R.id.et_pre_rucka_moday,
    R.id.et_insulin_monday_pre_rucka, R.id.et_posle_rucka_monday, R.id.et_pre_vecere_moday, R.id.et_insulin_monday_pre_vecere, R.id.et_posle_vecere_monday,
    R.id.et_pred_spavanje_moday, R.id.et_insulin_monday_pred_spavanje};
    List<Day> days = mDatabase.getAllDaysByWeek(week.getTitle());

    int count = 0;

    for (int id : ids) {
        EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(id);
        values.add(t.getText().toString());
        t.addTextChangedListener(this);
        applyChangedEditTextColor(false, values, t);
        // Here i should implement some logic like and apply for all edittexts
        // for (Day day : days) {
        // 
        // }
    }
```

Comment: Explain where the `nasteValues` are coming, you get 7 diff values and you want to set each on a specific day. But since we don't know the values you want to set, this is no possible to help.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: So you have one Edittext per day ?

Comment: Well i have many Edittexts per day, but i have shown here only one Edittext per day, so i don't confuse anyone. Actually i have shown two EditTexts per day `etNasteMonday` and `etInsulinMondayBeforeBreak`

Comment: Yes but for a specific attribute in your class Day, you have one EditText per day. So there is a "solution". Give me 10min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a lot of EditText to use. I would create some Arrays to store the instance an recover those in a loop.

```
EditText[] nasteEdit = new EditText[]{ /* your seven instance of editText for naste value in correct order */};
List<Day> days = mDatabase.getAllDaysByWeek(week.getTitle());

int cntDays = 0;
for (Day day : days) {
    String getNasteMonday = nasteEdit[cntDays] != null ? nasteEdit[cntDays].getText().toString() : null;
    double nasteValue = convertStringToDouble(getNasteMonday);
    day.setNaste(nasteValue);

    // SAME FOR OTHER ATTRIBUTE
    mDatabase.updateDay(day);

   cntDays++;
}
```

During the loop, I get the correct EditText and create the value. I keep you for-iterative loop here and use an external counter but this should work.

You just need to do this for every attributes `Day` have and this will work.

The array need to have the instance of the EditText, so don't waste you time to get the text of each ;)

Hope this will work, I can't test it write now.

Comment: You are welcom. For big screen with to much of fields, you need to use array or any kind of collection to use a generic form of code. Otherwise you end up with 1000lines of duplicated code.

Comment: That is what i wanted to ask you now. How can i initialize all these EditTexts with a few lines of code.

Comment: I guess but this wasn't clear, You mostly speak about loops so this was confusing.

Comment: I am not sure of what you want, if this is to far from this question don't hesitate to create a new one.

Comment: Can you help me with my new question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. The better approach would be to use regular for loop and using method get() from List, for getting the position of element in a list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
    Day day1 = days.get(0);
    day1.setNaste(3.0);
    Day day2 = days.get(1);
    day2.setNaste(2.0);
    Day day3 = days.get(2);
    Day day4 = days.get(3);
    Day day5 = days.get(4);
    Day day6 = days.get(5);
    Day day7 = days.get(6);
}
```

If you need to update some data from database then you will declare object Day outside the for loop and call that object in update method from database:

```
database.updateDay(day1);
database.updateDay(day2);
```

Comment: With this kind of repetition, this is cleary not the best solution !

Comment: Yes, thank you, however, you could have updated the individual 2 days before the loop, then use the enhanced for loop to update all in the database. There is no reason to extract all 7 objects from the list

Comment: @AxelH Any other suggestion? I know this is not the best solution, but it's working for me.

Comment: Need to know were the Naste values come from for that. Look a the comment on the question.